# How can I tell when a site graduated from beta?

Tags: support, area-51, stackexchange.com, graduating-sites

I was browsing through the [newest sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest) and the [Area51 list of launched sites](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched). The *Site age* at the site overview appears to relate to the start of public beta, not to the graduation from beta to "golden". The Area51 page tells us the commitment start, private beta start and the public beta start. But where can I find out how long ago a site graduated and became a full-fledged member of the community?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]